# Javascript strings with symbol '\'

Tags: javascript

I am having difficulties handling symbol \ in javascript. Strings seems to ignore it, for example `alert('a\b')` would only alert `a`.

My goal is to write following function which would give me latex image:

```
function getLatexImage(tex)
{
    return 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=' + tex;
}
```

However calling `getLatexImage('\frac{a}{b}')` gives me: `"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=rac{a}{b}"`

`\f` is being ignored.

Any suggestions?

Comment: escape the symbol -put  '\\'  instead of '\'

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Pretty sure you could have used search to find this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` is an escape character. It starts an escape sequence.

`\n` is a new line. `\t` is a tab. An escape sequence that has no special meaning usually gets turned into the character on the RHS (so `\b` is `b`).

To have a backslash as data in a string literal you have to escape it:

```
alert('a\\b');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `\\`. Single slashes are used for special signs (like `\n`, `\t`..)

Answer (score 2):

The backslash `\` is a escape character in JavaScript and many other programming languages. If you want to output it, you'll need to escape it by itself.

```
\\a
```

for example would output `\a`.

That being said, if you want to use it in an url you should encode it for safety.

```
%5c
```

translates to \

Comment: Or go over the top like me and url encode everything!  +1 for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply escape it by adding another backslash

```
 '\\b'
```